# Unable to deploy tomcat server with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have been trying to deploy my tomcat server for a couple of days using spring boot but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong with my configuration. I have looked at a couple of suggestions online but I still cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have a feeling it could be something little but at this point, I don't think I'm getting anywhere with the issue

I have my maven configuration file and am trying to leverage the apache tomcat maven plugin in deploying my server.

> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>               4.0.0
>
> ```
>         <groupId>com.blah.maven</groupId>
>         <artifactId>blah</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>         <packaging>war</packaging>
>         <name>foo</name>
>
>         <properties>
>             <springframework.boot.version>1.5.9.RELEASE</springframework.boot.version>
>         </properties>
>
>         <parent>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
>             <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
>         </parent>
>
>         <dependencies>
>             <dependency>
>                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>                 <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
>             </dependency>
>         </dependencies>
>
>         <build>
>             <plugins>
>                 <plugin>
>                     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
>                     <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>                     <version>2.2</version>
>                     <configuration>
>                         <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
>                         <path>/blah</path>
>                     </configuration>
>                 </plugin>
>
>                 <plugin>
>                     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>                     <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>                     <version>${springframework.boot.version}</version>
>                 </plugin>
>             </plugins>
>         </build>
>
>
>     </project>
> ```

And in my project I have an Application class

```
    package foo;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
    import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
    import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

        public static void main(String [] args){
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application){
            return application.sources(Application.class);
        }
    }
```

Here's a screen shot of my stack

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli)
>   on project whot: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused
>   (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]
>     org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy
>   (default-cli) on project whot: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager       at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>         at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>         at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>         at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>         at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>         at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>         at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)         at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)      at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)       at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)         at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)       at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)         at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>         at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>         at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>         at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>         at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)     Caused
>   by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke
>   Tomcat manager        at
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
>         at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>         at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>         ... 21 more     Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused (Connection refused)      at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)         at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>         at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>         at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>         at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)       at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)      at
>   org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
>         at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
>         at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
>         at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
>         at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
>         at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
>         at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:742)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:705)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:388)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:82)
>         at
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
>         ... 24 more     [ERROR]     [ERROR]     [ERROR] For more information about
>   the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>     [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: Please, can you share the error?

Comment: Connection refused (Connection refused): Have you configured Tomcat Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to configure the Tomcat Authentication.

**Follow this example from** https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat

[image]

**And at Maven side:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That was a total brain fart on my part. I was trying to deploy the application (mvn tomcat: deploy) without actually having the an instance of tomcat running. What I really wanted to do was create and run an instance of tomcat in my maven project(mvn tomcat: run).

Could not believe I spent quite a lot of time on something so trivial. Oh well, live and learn.